# Deleting Special character from a text file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a text file and I want to remove Special Characters from that file. For example:-
the entries in the text files

```
++Mathematics
--Chemistry
(Physics)
$#History)
%%Geography
```

Now I want to replace all of the special characters from strings in the text file and want the output as:-
Mathematics
Chemistry
Physics
History
Geography

I have used the replace command in my powershell script but in spite of replacing the special characters, it is deleting all the values from my text file.

```
get-content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit.txt
Foreach-object {$_ -replace "\&", "" -replace "\£", "" -replace "\+", "" -replace "\-", "" -replace "\)","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\$","" -replace "\#","" -replace "\*",""}|
Set-Content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit1.txt

get-content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit.txt
```

Meanwhile can someone also suggest how to start learning powershell. I am a newbie in powershell and want to learn Powershell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit.txt)) {
    $line -replace "\&", "" -replace "\£", "" -replace "\+", "" -replace "\-", "" -replace "\)","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\$","" -replace "\#","" -replace "\*","" -replace "\%",""
} | Set-Content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit1.txt

Get-Content D:\Share\SCCM-Powershell_Commands\edit1.txt
```